# In java Program I am getting yellow exclamation Mark and not showing output on console

Tags: java

[This is the image i am getting. Please help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvxGf.jpg)
I am new at programming so take a look in this matter. Also program output not showing on console. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste the code here rather than image.

Comment: "Yellow exclamation mark" indicates to a compile warning. In your case unused `java.util.regex` library causes it.  - [http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Program/console is waiting for input from user.It will take integer input. Try Giving input from keyboard like : 10

Answer (score 0):

Within eclipse, these yellow icons mean: the built-in java compiler has a warning for you. Just move your mouse over the icon to see the warning; or open the "Problems" pane to see it.

In this case, it warns about an **unused** import. The quickest way is to press ctrl-shift-o; that makes eclipse organize your imports; and it will simply remove that line.

And in order to not be fooled by consoles **waiting** for your input, always do something like:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
```

**prior** to use the Scanner to wait for user input!

In general: make sure that there are **zero** warnings in your code. Always. No exceptions.

Comment: Thanks i have now understand the problem. As per instructions of GhostCat i have resolved the issue. Now the exclamation mark is gone and i am getting the output. Thanks of your help.

Comment: You are welcome. If so, feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the import libraries are not being used.